# php curl does not execute url

Tags: php, cron, curl

Im writing a php cron script that needs to run a url

After some database modifications the php script needs to execute an url

```
$url = 'http://server.domain.com/cronjob.php?idorder='.$orderid.'&idcustomer='.$idklant;
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/errorlog.txt', 'w');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// debug 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
//
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $url.'<br>';
```

The error log shows
* About to connect() to server.domain.com port 80 (#0)

- Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... * Connection timed out
- couldn't connect to host
- Closing connection #0

But when I run the $url direct in a browser window it works

Comment: Are you able to visit the URL via web browser no problem?

Comment: Something in your server setup prevents the connection to this URL. Most likely it is the firewall. It could also be something in the way the network is set up. More information on the provider and its network is needed to judge if the reason is there.

Comment: indeed It was the network, apparently connecting form the internal lan to public was forbidden. 
Changing the code to:
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].' solved the problem.